# updating object using saveOrUpdate in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am familiar with Hibernate.I have a question.

Lets say I do `session.saveOrUpdate(object)`. If object contains some 'id'(object identifier), then it means update query will be fired if the object is modified.

I want to know how does Hibernate do that i.e. there could be 'n' number of fields in the object.Does Hibernate check each and every field to know if any field is modified(in this case update query to be fired)?

Answer (score 2):

While using  use `.saveOrUpdate()` it will check if the object  has no identifier property and if so it will make it persistent by generating it the identifier and assigning it to session.

> if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing if
>   another object associated with the session has the same identifier,
>   throw an exception if the object has no identifier property, save() it
>   if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly
>   instantiated object, save() it if the object is versioned by a
>    or , and the version property value is the same
>   value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it otherwise
>   update() the object

[From Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent)

Comment: so even if no field is modified, still update query will  be fired?

Comment: yes it will fire.Because it will check only the identifier field

Comment: ok..i thought that if no field is modified, update will not be fired. Isn't it a performance issue?? i mean if no change is there in the field, then why to fire update query..

Comment: In my knowledge it only checks the id.You are right in this case .Updation is not necessary.But it is not working like that.You can observe by putting show_sql to true

Comment: The nHibernate Session keeps track of what needs writing to the database, if you commit a transaction it only updates objects that have changed or inserts new objects.

Comment: nHibernate  means is it different from normal hibernate?

Comment: i searched in the net it is for dot net applications but he asked for java applications

Answer (score 0):

It checks the field(s) mapped as the identifier for the given object, if the object doesn't have an identifier it calls Save() which `INSERTS` the object,  if it does it calls Update() which `UPDATES` it

Answer (score 0):

Basically in hibernate if you set object with unique identifier any how it is going to update the whole row by calling 
`session.saveOrUpdate();`

or if unique identifier not found it insert the data.